# OpenGL starter project

Tags: linux, opengl

I would like to learn OpenGL programming on LINUX.  I have found that I learn the quickest if I have a small self contained working project I can study and tweak.  I could work with C, C++ or python source code.

Where can I find a good starter OpenGL example project that builds without too much hassle on Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nehe is a really good teacher of OpenGL
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01
The lessons are windows based but at the buttom of the page you can find vcodes for other os.

This is the link for the basic openGL app for linux:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/linux/lesson01.tar.gz

Edit:
Check out te glut library also it makes things easier.

Here some nice samples too.
http://www.codesampler.com/linuxsrc.htm

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at Panda3D ? It is a framework for 3D rendering and game development for Python and C++ programs. They have a series of examples to get you started. http://www.panda3d.org/

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, [nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) is not that bad.

But if you [google it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=opengl+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), you will get lots of opengl tutorials. Just pick 1.